# Bash pattern matching or regex inside while loop for extracting and enriching data (from json to cmd console)

Tags: bash

I have data in .json like this

```
[
 "items": 
    [
         {
            "dateAdd": "2019-06-21 13:48:22",
            "status": "Disconnected",
            "name": "PLVM32",
            "lastKeepAlive": "2022-07-14 14:10:21",
            "id": "972"
         },
         {
            "dateAdd": "2019-06-21 13:48:23",
            "status": "Never connected",
            "name": "PLVN50",
            "id": "973"
         },
         {
            "dateAdd": "2019-03-05 09:24:04",
            "status": "Active",
            "name": "PWVEAC",
            "lastKeepAlive": "2022-09-12 04:21:09",
            "id": "009"
       }
    ]
]
```

then I have a script like this,
read line by line, when if[[ $line == $nameCheck ]] is true,
pause for a while, then do a check one line below the matching line,

if the condition if[[ a == lastKeepCheck ]] is true,
then the value of $lastKeepCheck is printed to the console directly,
otherwise what is printed to the console is NULL

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/root/agentDisconnect.json"

nameCheck="name"
lastKeepCheck="lastKeepAlive"

while IFS= read -r line
do
   if [[ $line == nameCheck ]]; then
       a=$line+1
      if[[ a == lastKeepCheck ]]; then
          echo "$a";
   else
      echo "NULL"
done < "$file"
```

the result to be displayed in the console is as follows:

```
 [root@PLVWZHUTD201 ~]#./script.sh
     2022-07-14 14:10:21
     NULL
     2022-09-12 04:21:09
```

how should my script be correct to run properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To process JSON, use a JSON-aware tool:

```
jq -r '.items[] | .lastKeepAlive | .//="NULL"' $file
```

Comment: Your suggestion is good, and it definitely works, it's just that the command is not found here, because I ran this on the office isolate (CentOS) server, couldn't update the package, couldn't install the python library, etc.

Comment: is there any other alternative if using awk? or a special bash script for this case?

Comment: You can write your own JSON parser, but it's not an easy task.

Comment: python or perl would be an alternative imho.

Comment: Perl has [JSON::PP](http://p3rl.org/JSON::PP) in the core, but CentOS used to amputate parts of it...